# Panicking Internally vs Internally Panicking?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

Which order (Panicking internally/ Internally panicking) is correct or more widely accepted and why?

Comment: Please consider visiting [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). This question is better suited there.

Answer (score 0):

Either order would be fine here.  Though semantically the same, putting an adverb after the verb will also emphasize the adverb a bit more, especially at the end of a sentence.  Compare "He was constantly complaining." versus "He was complaining constantly."